# Call c++ function in Widget blueprint

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I create widget, inherited from C++ class below.

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Blueprint/UserWidget.h"
#include "Widget_Manager.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class CRY_API UWidget_Manager : public UUserWidget
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, Category ="test")
    int32 x;
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "test")
    int32 increase_x(int32 i);
};
```

I want to output the value of x in value1, then increase it, and output it to value2.
My problem is that the blueprints do not see the function `increase_x()`.
Not in elements list, not in function search.
[image]

Also i tried property `CallInEditor`.
How I can call this function in widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that your not using Hot Reload (the Compile C++ button in the Editor).

If you make changes to your C++ code, especially Headers, always close the Editor and recompile it from Visual Studio. Hot Reload cannot resolve changes to Header files, which means things like Functions and new Properties will not be available in Blueprint if your using Hot Reload until you do a recompile from Visual Studio.

Also its best to leave Context Sensitivity on.

Comment: Function is visible after compile in visual studio. I'm new at UE4 and this fact explain for me, why Hot Reload many times faster then compile in VS. Thanks for help!